# Need to delete commit on remote that is part of deleted branch showing up in closed merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a commit in a remote branch, lets call the branch "mistake", that needs to be deleted. The merge request was closed without being merged anywhere upstream.

The remote branch itself was already deleted, however I can still see the commit in diffs of the closed request.

I can get the content I want vanished back if I pull down from the merge request refs locally.

I have tried git-filter-branch and BFG and while both appear to successfully remove the reference that I'm trying to get rid of, I still can see the commit in the diff of the merge request. I'm not a project owner so I can't explicitly delete the merge request.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I also tried creating a local branch of the same name of the deleted one, pulling down from the merge commit, reverting to before the problem commit, and force pushing. It didn't work either.

Here's resources I've worked with already to accomplish this:

- Used [BFG][1] to clean the specific file that is the problem, it says it cleaned up dirty references but when I look on my remote, I can still see it in the diff. Here's what happened when I first ran it, and it looked correct - it listed changing a merge, which was where I needed it:

````
    Using repo : /Users/xxx/Code/my-company-repo.git
Found 2 objects to protect
Found 9 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/master, refs/heads/xxxxx, ...
Protected commits
-----------------
These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered:
 * commit xxxxxxxx (protected by 'HEAD')
Cleaning
--------
Found 33 commits
Cleaning commits:       100% (33/33)
Cleaning commits completed in 96 ms.
Updating 2 Refs
---------------
    Ref                           Before     After   
    -------------------------------------------------
    refs/merge-requests/1/head  | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx
    refs/merge-requests/1/merge | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx
Updating references:    100% (2/2)
...Ref update completed in 40 ms.
Commit Tree-Dirt History
------------------------
    Earliest                   Latest
    |                               |
    ..DDD............................
    D = dirty commits (file tree fixed)
    m = modified commits (commit message or parents changed)
    . = clean commits (no changes to file tree)
                            Before     After   
    -------------------------------------------
    First modified commit | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx
    Last dirty commit     | xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxx
Deleted files
-------------
    Filename            Git id           
    -------------------------------------
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxx (1.5 KB)
In total, 5 object ids were changed. Full details are logged here:
    /Users/xxx/Code/my-company.git.bfgreport/2020-10-12/15-52-26
BFG run is complete! When ready, run: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive```
````

So I followed those instructions, but I'm still seeing it in the merge now a couple hours later. Rerunning the command, it appears from bfg's side it no longer sees it because the second time I got this:

```
   Using repo : /Users/xxx/Code/xxx.git
   Found 2 objects to protect
   Found 9 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/master, refs/heads/xxx, ...
   Protected commits
   -----------------
   These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered:
    * commit xxxxx (protected by 'HEAD')
   Cleaning
   --------
   Found 33 commits
   Cleaning commits:       100% (33/33)
   Cleaning commits completed in 166 ms.
   BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??
```

I could see the things that might resolve my situation being:

- Ability to delete a commit on the remote that is orphaned (no branch)
- I was able to pull from the merge request commit, if I could push back I guess I could do a force push and if I got rid (locally) of the problem commit, fix it that way? However trying the inverse of pulling from the MR to push back, it fails, because I guess its not pushing back to a valid destination
- Remotely delete the closed MR altogether, I don't think I can do this through the API from what I've read as I am not a project owner

**Update 1:**

So from the BFG side I see it was a partial success. When I try pulling down directly from merge refs, I no longer get the problem file.

However it is still visible in the cached diff...

**Update 2:**

I have maintainer privileges on the project

Comment: When you say "It didn't work either." - What does this mean? Can you show some output from these commands?

Comment: That does not look like like a git problem to me. More of a gitlab (or equivalent) problem. With no project permission I doubt anything can be done without server admin intervention. You are simply not in control of the repo that actually needs being BFG'd.

Comment: I added some additional context above

Comment: If the request has been merged, the commit is in the owner's repo. There is nothing you can do about it. But I guess you have already figured out that part.

Comment: It was never merged, I would have mentioned that

Comment: @JTK it is still in the remote repo, under some ref you do not have control over, which I assume gitlab wants to keep not to break its MR history.